# R: adding logical to sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I am trying to run this code:

```
check_zeros <- function(x) { # WIP
  if (x == 0) { 
    !(df[gsub('\\b0+','',format(as.Date(formation$study_start_dates_list[i]),'%m/%d/%Y')), names(x)] == df[gsub('\\b0+','',format(as.Date(formation$study_end_dates_list[i]),'%m/%d/%Y')), names(x)]) 
  } 
}

remove_undesired_stocks2 <- function(n) {

  i = 1
  listofdfs_filtered <- list()


  for (i in 1:n) {
    a <- subset(average_returns, row.names(average_returns) == i)
    b <- as.data.frame(sapply(subset(average_returns, row.names(average_returns) == i), function(x) all(x == 0 | is.nan(x) | check_zeros(x) )))
    c <- a[, !b]
    listofdfs_filtered[[i]] <- c
  }
  return(listofdfs_filtered)
}
```

Error comes out as:
`Error in if (x == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I think it is bc there is a `NaN` going into `x == 0` of the `check_zeros` function.

Any how I can overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Overcome it by putting in safeguard checks before `(x == 0)`, including `length(x) == 1`, `!is.na(x)`, `!is.nan(x)`, etc. Defensive programming suggests that you should prepare for unexpected inputs, so you can also check for `!is.numeric(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it myself:

the check_zero function is constructed in a way which cannot take objects with length > 1. more specifically logic inside **`if` cannot use objects length > 1**.

Since I was using a object with `length > 1`, there was an error

You **should use `ifelse` in this case**:

```
check_zeros <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x == 0, (df[gsub('\\b0+','',format(as.Date(formation$study_start_dates_list[i]),'%m/%d/%Y')), names(x)] == df[gsub('\\b0+','',format(as.Date(formation$study_end_dates_list[i]),'%m/%d/%Y')), names(x)]), FALSE)
}
```

Cheers.